# OpenGL and GLUT keyboard function

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, keyboard-events

How can I register that the CTRL key is depressed? The following code works for all keys except CTRL:

```
switch (key)
{
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    cout << "right key" << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
    cout << "left key" << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    cout << "up key" << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
    cout << "down key" << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
case GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL:
    cout << "CTRL pressed" << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLUT cannot detect *just* the press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. This fact is also hinted at by the fact that the "enumerator" for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not GLUT_**KEY**_CTRL, but GLUT_**ACTIVE**_CTRL.

However, you can query the state of `Ctrl` when another key is pressed:

```
case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
    cout << "right key";
    if (glutGetModifiers() & GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL)
        cout << " w/Ctrl";
    cout << endl;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Redraw the scene
    break;
```

See the [documentation of `glutGetModifiers()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node73.html) for more details.